# Checking if a treeNode is an ancestor of another node

Tags: python, tree

```
def is_ancestor(node, middle):
    # search down
    if node.data == middle.data:
        return True
    if node.left:
        is_ancestor(node.left, middle)
    if node.right:
        is_ancestor(node.right, middle)
    return False
```

I am using this function to recursively check is a `node` is an ancestor of `middle`.

Let's say we have a tree that looks like

```
    5
   /
  2
   \
    4
```

and I say that node is the node that points to `5` and middle is `2`.

When calling `is_ancestor(node_with_5, node_with_2)`, I am expecting to recursively move the `node` down both to left and right and return True whenever it finds the `middle`.

However, my current function gives me `False` even though it will find the `middle` in the first recursion call.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make some little changes à la:

```
def is_ancestor(node, middle):
    if node is middle:  # data could coincide, compare nodes directly 
        return True
    if node.left and is_ancestor(node.left, middle):
        return True  # do actually return something
    if node.right and is_ancestor(node.right, middle):
        return True  # do actually return something
    return False
```

You could get the entire logic in an even more concise way:

```
def is_ancestor(node, middle):
    if node is None:
        return False
    if node is middle:
        return True
    return is_ancestor(node.left, middle) or is_ancestor(node.right, middle)
```

Comment: The approach is absolutely fine.